# Loading a binary file into a array

Tags: c, arrays, file, binary

I'm having trouble loading my file .dat into an array. 
I have a created a structure and loaded the file in the program.

I think I need to use a loop to go through the file and use fread to get the data outta file and place into the array.

The file is a binary file if you cant guess!:)

```
/* Libary collections required */

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* The user must be able to make a selection between printing out the CD list with
   either the track lists or without. Which will be done using a switch case.. later*/

typedef struct CDFull
{
    char CDTitle[50];
    char Artist[50];
    int NumberOfTracks;
    int TrackNumber;
    char TrackName[50];
    float TrackLength;
}CDF;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    /* Checking whether or not the file has been loaded.
       Prints a different output dependant on the result */

    FILE * file = fopen("test.dat","rb");

    if(!file)
    {
        printf("We are unable to read the file!");
    }

    else if(file)
    {
        printf("The file has successfully loaded!");
    }

    /* Load the file into a array data structure */

    /* I need to create a array calling in the data from the file inside a loop.
       ending the read when the file is null/empty/whitespace */

    CDF myCData[51];  
    for(int i = 0; i < 51; i++)
    {
    fread(&myCData[i], sizeof(CDF), 1,file);
    }

    fclose(file);
    getchar();
    return 0;   

}
```

Hope that is clear enough, I've been at for hours on end without any success

Thanks for responses in advance.

Edit: Added what BLUEPIXY said: It compiles, however, I need to print the array out to check whether or not the data has loaded.. we will see hehe!

Comment: maybe `char myCData[51];` --> `CDF myCData[51];` ... `fread(&myCData[i], sizeof(CDF), 1, ,file);`

Comment: Was the data written with this same structure `CDF`? If not, you might be suffering from structure padding issues (and you would not be the first today).

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: @Jongware : CDF is the same structure as the binary file.  I modified what BLUEPIXY said a little: for(int i = 0; i < 51; i++)
 {
 fread(&myCData[i], sizeof(CDF), 1,file);
 }

Comment: try add `printf("title:%s\n", myCData[i].CDTitle);` after fread...;

Comment: 1. One should use the result of `fread()`.  2.  The data you are reading may be "packed", but `CDF`  may not be packed.  (I see @ Jongware has eluded to that.)

Comment: It works kinda like I wanted. I understand what I need for this program now. Thank you for your time, kinda understand what I need to do now to apply this to the rest of the functions I want... yay! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following issues, in my opinion.

### Memory Allocation

For what looks like a fairly large file, I would much rather allocate on the heap than on the stack. As opposed to `CDF myCData[51];` you should be doing `CDF *myCData = malloc(50 * sizeof(CDF));` which would give you a dynamic allocation as opposed to static.

### Array Size

If you noticed above, I allocated for 50 and not 51, which is because your `for` is only traversing through the first 50. Unless I'm missing something, and pardon me if I am indeed, you're allocating an extra `sizeof(CDF)` which is certainly not necessary and is an insecurity.

### Structure Packing & Padding

Depending on the platform you're compiling this on, and also depending on the compiler (behaviour is implementation defined) you're structure is not portable and is certainly going to give you headaches when it comes to interpreting in the future, owing to padding or packing inconsistencies. Padding is essentially filling in gaps between variables within a structure to ensure that every variable is on an address which is a factor of the word length. *This is enabled by default.* Packing on the other hand — which is a lack of padding, by the way — is not. To ensure things work as planned, the following are your options.

1. If you are going for space savings (for whatever reason) and are not running this on a RISC machine, please go ahead and enable packing on GCC (which means, disabling padding!) by adding `__attribute__((__packed__))` to the `struct` definition. Please note that although this will save space, it will considerably slow down your code on architectures like allow it (CISC like x86, amd64)* and will not run on architectures which disallow the lack of strict alignment.
2. If you don't want to pack and keep your code faster, *ALWAYS* put the data types in your structure in a decreasing order of their size. This will prevent any *internal padding* and thus reduce padding to a minimum, that is just the *trailing padding*.

*SSE2 instructions on x86 CPUs do require the data to be 128-bit (16-byte) aligned and there can be substantial performance advantages from using aligned data on these architectures.